# Pass-through queries and linked table queries using different connections

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

<sub>Follow-on to an earlier question: [Force SET IDENTITY_INSERT to take effect faster from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987721)</sub>

I'm in the process of upsizing from an MS Access backend to a SQL Server backend.  Many of the tables have autonumber primary keys.  I'm trying to populate them as follows (pseudocode):

```
ExecutePassThru "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Accounts ON"
db.Execute "INSERT INTO sql_Accounts SELECT * FROM mdb_Accounts"
ExecutePassThru "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Accounts OFF"
```

In the above code, `sql_Accounts` is a linked table connected to the Accounts table in SQL Server and `mdb_Accounts` is a linked table connected to the Accounts table in the mdb.  This fails with the error,

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Accounts' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I fired up SQL Server Profiler to try to figure out the problem and the issue is that each line of code in my sample may or may not use a different Server Process ID (SPID).  In other words, they are using different connections to the backend.

**Is there some way to ensure they all use the same connection?**

Comment: A single ADO connection to SQL Server could allow you to SET IDENTITY_INSERT and insert one row at a time.  Is that an improvement?

Comment: Maybe.  I considered that since that is what Access is actually doing behind the scenes.  I was hoping for a simpler fix before I refactored a whole bunch of code, but that might be my only option.

Comment: I just came across the [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/tags/migrate+from+access/).  It looks promising, but it's currently insisting that I install the Access 2010 runtime to use it.  I know the 2010 runtime is a free install, but I'd rather not have to battle with multiple versions of Access on my dev machine.

Comment: I don't see that requirement listed; perhaps it's to satisfy "DAO provider version 12.0 or 14.0. You can install DAO provider from Microsoft Office 2010/2007 product or download it from Microsoft web site."  I think you can install ACE separately.  But ... is this something you're intending to do at the client location?

Comment: I tried installing just the Access Database Engine Redistributable, but that was not enough.  I'm currently working on implementing your suggestion from your first comment.  I'll try to post back with updates as I make progress.

Comment: The SSMA will work with A2007 installed instead (I thought it said that during the installation?).

Comment: From the list of [System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=207#system-requirements): "*DAO provider version 12.0 or 14.0. You can install DAO provider from Microsoft Office 2010/2007 product or download it from Microsoft web site.*"  The Access Runtime is not specifically listed as a system requirement (as @HansUp mentioned earlier).  I'm currently developing with Access 2002 so whether I install the runtime for Access 2007 or 2010, I would still be introducing an add'l Access version.

Comment: @David: Have you used the SSMA?  Is it a worthwhile tool?

Comment: I've used the SSMA and I think it's great -- much better than the upsizing wizard because it allows you to stage the upsizing without actually doing it in order to figure out what won't convert. Then you can fix the problems and run the test again, until you have perfect, error-free conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, however this a one time conversion and it's not worth too deep of dive trying to do complex things with connection reuse.

1. Create a staging table on the SQL Server that does not contain an identity but is otherwise of the same schema.
2. Load your data to that table
3. Do your identity insert entirely on the SQL Server side.