# Transfering content of mdb tables to SQL Server repeatedly

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, insert

I need to create a facility to enable users to repeatedly transfer the contents of  tables in an `.mdb` to identically structured tables in SQL Server  (emphasis on 'user' and 'repeatedly').

- I wish to avoid the 'built-in' management tools of SQL Server
- My preference is for using SQL Server express
- I don't want to re-create the SQL database or table structures each time

Is my only option a loop through the rows of the `.mdb` table, while INSERTing its contents line by line?

If the answer is yes, what limit can I expect to the number of rapid INSERTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert the rows one by one.

Link the SQL Server tables into Access with something like

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
    TransferType:=acLink, _
    DatabaseType:="ODBC", _
    DatabaseName:="your ODBC connect string", _
    ObjectType:=acTable, _
    Source:="dbo.Table1", _
    Destination:="dbo_Table1", _
    StructureOnly:=False, _
    StoreLogin:=True
```

and then insert all rows with one command from mdb to SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO dbo_Table1 SELECT * FROM Table1
```

If you have IDENTITY columns, things get more complicated.
Find some hints here: [Pass-through queries and linked table queries using different connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000235/pass-through-queries-and-linked-table-queries-using-different-connections)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that in mdbs themselves are generated by software. I have no control over placing code  etc in the mdbs.

Comment: @srm2710: If you want to automate this process, you will have to run code *somewhere*. E.g. have a "TransferControl" mdb with code, where you link the tables from each data mdb plus the SQL tables.