# Another ODBC Call Failed Topic

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, pass-through

I am running Access 2010 FE and SQL Server 2005 BE.
I can execute pass through queries to my SQL Server succesfully by using DSNless connections.

During my testing phase sometimes I need to restore my database to get back to my original records so I can rerun my pass through queries. What I have found is when I run a pass through query, it creates an active connection on my SQL Server. I see the connection via the SQL Server Management Console under the MANAGEMENT | SQL Server Logs | Activity Monitor, select view processes. There I can see which process ID is being used and who is using it when I run my pass through query.

Now the only way for me to restore my database is to KILL the PROCESS e.g. Active connection

Now when I have my restored database in place and re-run the pass through query, I receive a ODBC -- Call Failed message box. I have attempted to run a procedure to refresh my querydefs but to no avail, I will still get the ODBC-- Call Failed message box when I click on those objects.

Now there are two options on how to fix this problem, which in either case I find not USER Friendly.

- Restart my Access Application
- Wait approx 5-10 minutes to rerun the Pass Through Query

I created a function to trap my ODBC Errors and this is what appears:

ODBC Error Number: 0
Error Description: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure

ODBC Error Number: 3146
Error Description: ODBC--call failed.

So if for some reason, I need to restart my SQL server or kill a process (Active Connection) on my SQL server while the Access Application is currently connected via ODBC, the objects created via ODBC will not perform properly till I execute the 2 workaround solutions as stated above.

Can anyone shed some advice on a solution? I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question some time ago, and never got a satisfactory answer.  My original question is here: [Force SET IDENTITY_INSERT to take effect faster from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987721/force-set-identity-insert-to-take-effect-faster-from-ms-access)

There is a registry setting [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177636.aspx) for ACE that controls the timeout behavior:

> **ConnectionTimeout**: The number of seconds a cached connection can remain idle before timing out. The default is 600 (values are of type REG_DWORD).

So as a third workaround (in addition to the two you already listed) you can change that registry setting to a shorter timeout (like 10 seconds).  This is the approach I took in my answer.  One caveat is that shortening the timeout may cause performance or other issues.  Your mileage may vary.

See my [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987721/force-set-identity-insert-to-take-effect-faster-from-ms-access/6988650#6988650) to the original question for more info.

Comment: Thank you Ill look into your reply, but I have other users using this application and I really hate to mess with their registry settings.  thanks again for your reply.