# How to execute SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF with a pass-through query from Access VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, pass-through

I have an Access db which has several tables linked. Now I'ld like to execute SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF on those tables. I googled and found things like this

```
Private mDb As Database
Public Sub SetIdentityInsert(strTableName As String, strOnorOff As String)
 Dim qdf As QueryDef
 Dim strSQL As String

 On Error GoTo Proc_Err

 Set qdf = mDb.QueryDefs("qryIDENTITY_INSERT")

 strSQL = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " & strTableName & " " & strOnorOff
 qdf.SQL = strSQL
 qdf.Execute

Proc_Exit:
 On Error Resume Next
 Set qdf = Nothing
 Exit Sub

Proc_Err:
 Resume Proc_Exit
 Resume
End Sub
```

from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/063270f6-0bb6-4630-85f5-b5b3a72e5295/turning-identityinsert-on-from-ms-access?forum=sqldataaccess

However, if I do this

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Passthru")
```

I complains that the passed string has to be one of DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, PROCEDURE or UPDATE.

I'm pretty sure this is possible somehow. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987721/force-set-identity-insert-to-take-effect-faster-from-ms-access) the author pastes example code calling a Sub ExecutePassThru, but the code for it is absent.

Comment: Can you double check the query type?  This error is normally returned by SELECT queries, not Pass-Throughs.

Comment: Where can I set the query type? I don't find such a property in QueryDef.

Comment: In addition to @GordThompson's excellent answer; you can also manually check.  Right click on your query.  Choose *Design View* from the menu.  Make sure the *Query Tools Design* ribbon is selected.  There are 9 buttons in the *Query Type* section of the ribbon: Select, Make Table, Append, ..., Pass-Through and Data Definition.  Check which is highlighted.

Comment: I have no query in design view. I know I can set the passthrough property there. I want to build a query in vba and pass it through to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [It] complains that the passed string has to be one of DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, PROCEDURE or UPDATE.

Access is not recognizing that the query is (intended to be) a pass-through query because the `.Connect` property of the `QueryDef` has not been set to a string that begins with "ODBC;". You need to set the `.Connect` property *before* you set the `.SQL` property.

Since you already have linked tables defined in the database you can just copy one of their `.Connect` properties, like this:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("Passthru")
qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("YourExistingLinkedTableName").Connect
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.SQL = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " & TheRestOfYourSqlCommand
```

Comment: I tried that and added qdf.ReturnsRecords = False. When I call execute, it now tells me  Laufzeitfehler '3146' ODBC-Aufruf fehlgeschlagen. Translate to english this means Error 3146 ODBC call failed.

Comment: Ah my query is SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Account] ON. If I run it in SSMS it tells me Table 'Account' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation. I thought I could just call it on every table before I copy. Thx.